Little nobs when displacing the UV from a texture
I followed this tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY&t=324s
To convert my shader noise displacement to a texture and then displace it with the dispose modifier.
Works great. The only thing is that I get these little nobs or nipples on both poles of the spheres ( I am using a sphere)  in the viewport I also see the UVs quite dramatically. I had to increase subdivision to 6 and I still saw the UVs ( at level 6 my RAM was directly full (64GB)
Does anyone know how I can get rid of the nipples and visible UVS? I need to print it with a surface as smooth as possible.
Best

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Otherwise it is pure guess about what is going wrong...

oh yes, sorry, new to this. is there a different website to upload to where you don't have to transfer the whole IP to the site?
